# How to send text with space from Android to MySQL database

Tags: php, android, mysql

Hello I'm new in Android and I wanna send a text from Android with space (" My Name is Oliver Queen ") to MySQL database.
I use this script in PHP:

```
<?php
$servername = " ";
$username = " ";
$password = " ";
$dbname = " ";

$id=$_GET['id'];
$project=$_GET["a"];

// Create connection..

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection

if ($conn->connect_error) {

 die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);

} 
//echo "$project";

$sql= $sql= "UPDATE user SET project = \"$project\" WHERE id= '$id'";  

$result = $conn->query($sql);

$conn->close();

?>
```

In MySQL I found only ("My") The first word before space! 
Plzz someone Help Mee !!!!!!

Comment: Not quite sure but change `"UPDATE user SET project = \"$project\" WHERE id= '$id'";` to `"UPDATE user SET project = "$project" WHERE id= '$id'";` - without back slash

Comment: Did you check your value of $project ?

Comment: Doesn't MySql use single quotes around string fields? Why use them around id and not project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the value of $project variable;
My bet is that you send values over a GET request, and not properly encoding them.

If your $project value is indeed "My" like I guess, then look up on you Android part, and look up on how to do url encoding (should be very simple in Java) - look for the equivalent of http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php - this should resolve your problem.

Also after you get it working, modify the code to deal with SQL Injections, switch to using PDO for DB access, and prepared statements, this would increase the security of your code.

Answer (score 1):

first of all, you should fix your query by using single quotes around the varchar attribute not the numeric, also pay attention to `$sql = $sql =` you declared it twice:

```
$sql= "UPDATE user SET project = '$project' WHERE id= $id";
```

then, you are trying to receive a string by GET method `$project=$_GET["a"];`, so your URL should be well encoded.